# How to get the table content value in java?

Tags: java, excel, jsp, servlets

Here, I am getting table content value (datatoexport) in servlet. But unable to get in excel page.
Getting empty page when download. Here, I am exporting table contents to excel in java.
Your help is highly appreciated.

JSP Code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Export to Excel - Demo</title>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<script language="javascript"> 
function exportToExcel()
{
    alert("test");
    $("#datatoexport").val( $("<div>").append( $("#exportTableSelector").eq(0).clone() ).html() );
    $('#myForm').submit();      
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm" action="Sample" method="post">
    <table id="exportTableSelector" align="left" border="2">
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="lightgreen">
                <th>Sr. No.</th>
                <th>Text Data</th>
                <th>Number Data</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            %>
            <tr bgcolor="lightblue">
                <td align="center"><%=i + 1%></td>
                <td align="center">This is text data <%=i%></td>
                <td align="center"><%=i * i%></td>
            </tr>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br><br>
    <p>
    some text
    </p>

    <input type="hidden" name="datatoexport" id="datatoexport" value="">
    <input type="hidden" value="excel_download" name="fileName" id="fileName">

    <a href="" onclick="exportToExcel();"  target="_blank" >Export to Excel</a>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class Sample
 */
public class Sample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Sample() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Inside doGet");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Inside doPost");
        actionExportToExcel(request, response);

    }

  public void actionExportToExcel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  {
        String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
        System.out.println("filename: " +fileName);
        String datatoexport = request.getParameter("datatoexport");
        System.out.println("datatoexport: " +datatoexport);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test_file.xls");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        System.out.println("datatoexport" +datatoexport);
  }

}
```

Comment: So the data is in an excel file and you only want to download it?

Comment: yes. I need to write the data to excel file and download it.. I am getting the data in my console.

Comment: Where does the data from the html page come from? at the moment there are only static values?

Comment: yes...getting from this string datatoexport in servlet from the jsp page.... $("#datatoexport").val( $("<div>").append( $("#exportTableSelector").eq(0).clone() ).html() );

Comment: In that case you do not need to send a request to the server - in javascript you can do:  window.open('data:vnd.ms-excel' + escape(datatoexport));

Comment: Can you please edit in my code @rob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like you are writing any data to the response. Try adding

```
response.getWriter().write(datatoexport);
response.getWriter().flush();
response.getWriter().close();
```

Comment: I am not getting the popup to download...after put this code

Comment: Working fine! But I am getting new window with blank page. After that, I am getting download option. If I delete target blank, If I click the hyperlink, it is not showing the download option

Answer (score 0):

First get the PrintWriter object from HttpServletResponse by

```
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
```

then try writing whatever you want to write like

```
out.println("Whatever you want to write.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it client side, without a server request by doing something like this:

```
function exportToExcel()
{
    var datatoexport = $("<div>").append( $("#exportTableSelector").eq(0).clone() ).html();
    window.open('data:vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8,' + escape(datatoexport));  
}
```

Comment: No. This will not work in IE 8 boss. That's why I am using it in server. Anyway thanks for your time

Comment: And can you pls tel me why I am getting blank new window?